# Not able to find all groups using a pattern regex in matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

I am trying to parse a regular expression in matlab. I am trying to extract all the number between '[]' for all the groups. Here are the details:

```
pat = '(\[\d,\d,\d,\d\])';
s1 = 'frame_1:[1,2,3,5],[11,22,33,44],[23,12,12,33],'

[matched_string] = regexp(s1,pat,'match');

>> matched_string{:}

ans =

    '[1,2,3,5]'
```

I want to get all the boxes, i.e [1,2,3,5],[11,22,33,44] and [23,12,12,33].

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try `pat = '\d+(?=[^]]*])';` if you want just the numbers inside brackets. Or `pat = '\[[\d,]+]'` to match digits and commas in brackets.

Comment: its giving me: ans =

    '4'


ans =
    '3'

Comment: Wel, `'\[[\d,]+]'` yields `{
  [1,1] = [1,2,3,5]
  [1,2] = [11,22,33,44]
  [1,3] = [23,12,12,33]
}`

Comment: pat = '\[[\d,]+]' worked thanks, but I am not sure why the (\[\d,\d,\d,\d\]) is not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your pattern only matches single digits inside square brackets. To match one or more, add `+` after each:

```
'(\[\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+\])'
```

If you do not care of the format inside the square brackets, and just need to extract square brackets with digits and commas inside, you may use a simpler

```
'\[[\d,]+]'
```

Note that `]` at the end of the regular expression is not a special char here, since there is no corresponding  `[` that opens a character class, thus, no need escaping it.

Comment: Another variant that collects sets of brackets containing no other brackets: `'\[[^\[\]]+]'`